# Angular $q Settle all

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I am learning Angular and creating a service for working with SharePoint data in the process. I have a function now that updates SharePoint items but I am having a problem. If the function is called and encounters an error while trying to update an item, all the items finish updating but only the first reject (failed item) is called. If any other items fail reject is not called for them. I would like to be able to push all errors generated into an array that I can pass back to the user so they may handle all of the errors. Below is my code:

```
this.UpdateListItems = function (webUrl, listName, itemsJson) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var promises = [];

    angular.forEach(itemsJson, function (itemProps) {
        var itemPromise = this.UpdateListItem(webUrl, listName, itemProps.Id, itemProps)
            .then(function (response) {
                return deferred.resolve(response);
            }, function (error) {
                return deferred.reject(error);
            });
        promises.push(itemPromise)
    }, this);

    return $q.all(promises)
        .then(function (data) {
            return lists[listName];
        }, function () {
            console.info("Promises: " + JSON.stringify(promises));
            return $q.reject(promises);
        });
};
```

Also here is the JSON promises returned. You will see 4 promise objects are returned with the first 2 being pending (they succeed) then the third one fails because the item doesn't exist on the server. Finally the 4th one should also fail for the same reason as the third but as you can see the reject returns immediately when the first one fails and doesn't process any further rejected items:

```
[
  {
    "$$state": {
      "status": 0,
      "pending": [
        [
          {
            "promise": {
              "$$state": {
                "status": 0
              }
            }
          },
          null,
          null,
          null
        ]
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$$state": {
      "status": 0,
      "pending": [
        [
          {
            "promise": {
              "$$state": {
                "status": 0
              }
            }
          },
          null,
          null,
          null
        ]
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$$state": {
      "status": 2,
      "value": {
        "data": {
          "error": {
            "code": "",
            "message": {
              "lang": "en-US",
              "value": "Resource not found for the segment 'TestList'."
            }
          }
        },
        "status": 404,
        "config": {
          "method": "GET",
          "transformRequest": [
            null
          ],
          "transformResponse": [
            null
          ],
          "url": "http://kl-sp10dev04/sites/angular/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/TestList(126)",
          "processData": false,
          "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
          }
        },
        "statusText": "Not Found"
      },
      "processScheduled": false
    }
  },
  {
    "$$state": {
      "status": 0,
      "pending": [
        [
          {
            "promise": {
              "$$state": {
                "status": 0
              }
            }
          },
          null,
          null,
          null
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: I believe you have to $q.defer() first and then you can add resolve or reject into $q.

Comment: Could you edit my code to show me what you mean? I am trying to do this but so far it's not working. Thanks.

Comment: I made an edit to your code, but I can see you've already got an answer. Your code is confusing because you're calling UpdateListItems inside UpdateListItems, seems like recursion but it's not. I'm confused what your code should be doing.

Comment: Almost, I am calling UpdateListItem inside UpdateListItem**s**, notice the s. UpdateListItem updates a single item and so it is called in a loop in the plural function to update multiple items

Comment: I see, I didn't notice the "s" well then it makes a bit more sense now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who runs into this problem in the future here is the answer. This is the code I am now using and it works as intended. That is it returns a promise which waits for all item promises to finish. If all items update successfully then it resolves by returning a reference to the JSON objects list. If any of items fails to update it rejects an array of all errors back to the user for error handling. Note that the Lists array is a property of the service so you don't see it defined here.

```
this.UpdateListItems = function (webUrl, listName, itemsJson) {
    var promises = [];
    var errors = [];
    angular.forEach(itemsJson, function (itemProps) {
        promises.push(this.UpdateListItem(webUrl, listName, itemProps.Id, itemProps)
            .then(function (response) {
                return itemsJson[listName];
            }, function (error) {
                errors.push(error);
            }));
    }, this);
    return $q.all(promises)
        .then(function () {
            if (errors.length > 0) {
                return $q.reject(errors);
            }
            else {
                return lists[listName]
            }
        });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It's asked by the community to **allow $q.all() to continue after one fails**, but it's not implemented by Angular. Some people have written some `$q` extras, such [this one](https://github.com/ohjames/angular-promise-extras).

After copy/paste, you will need to reference the `'angular-q-extras'` module in your code and call

```
  $q.allSettled(promises).then(results => ...//some fails, some not )
```

Now you can ca